# Making combobox visible when it is disabled

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am disabling combobox in VB.net.
But in disable mode it not visible properly.
I tried changing both BackColor and ForeColor but it is not working.

Code :

```
cmbbox.BackColor = Color.FromName("Window")
or
cmbbox.ForeColor = Color.FromName("Window")
```

Please help

Dear Adam:
I am making my component enable false.But I want to make it viewable.You can reffer the link.This is what exacly I want but in VB.Net : [A combobox that looks decent when it is disabled](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15078/A-combobox-that-looks-decent-when-it-is-disabled/?fid=330548&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&tid=4148440)

Comment: What property of the combobox are you changing specifically?

Comment: well, that's how it looks when you disable it actually.

Comment: Are you modifying the `Enabled` or `Visible` properties of the `ComboBox`? Setting `Visible` to false will not allow a user to see the control on your form. Setting `Enabled` to false leaves the control visible, but unusable and "grayed out". From your post, it's not completely clear what the problem is, but unless you have other requirements, I'd say you shouldn't have to modify the colors of the control.

Comment: Have you tried to convert any of the project you mentioned to VB.Net?

Comment: Yes I tried.But not able to convert

Answer (score 0):

To achieve disabling combobox without fading it, first change the dropdown style of the combobox to DropDownList, Then tweak with the events to achieve the goal.

Here is a piece of code by which you can achieve the same:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim selectindex As Integer
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("1")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("2")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("3")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("4")
    selectindex = 3
    ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectindex
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectindex
End Sub
End Class
```

Create anew form Form1 and add a combobox to the form, then add the above code to get a readonly combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this thread](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/34/173306.aspx) which has a solution for a readonly combobox and the code is all VB.NET.

A version of their code is as follows. You'll need to but it inside a class of your own which inherits `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`

```
    Private _ReadOnly As Boolean = False

    Public Property [ReadOnly]() As Boolean    
        Get
            Return _ReadOnly
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
            _ReadOnly = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function PreProcessMessage(ByRef msg As Message) As Boolean
        'Prevent keyboard entry if control is ReadOnly  
        If _ReadOnly = True Then
            'Check if its a keydown message
            If msg.Msg = &H100 Then
                'Get the key that was pressed 
                Dim key As Int32 = msg.WParam.ToInt32
                'Ignore navigation keys 
                If key = Keys.Tab Or key = Keys.Left Or key = Keys.Right Then
                    'Do nothing    
                Else
                    Return True
                End If
            End If
        End If
        'Call base method so delegates receive event 
        Return MyBase.PreProcessMessage(msg)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        'Prevent list displaying if ReadOnly
        If _ReadOnly = True Then
            If m.Msg = &H201 OrElse m.Msg = &H203 Then
                Return
            End If
        End If
        'Call base method so delegates receive event 
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same not long ago and ended up doing the following. You may not like it, but i'll share it in case. I am using `TableLayoutPanel` to arrange my controls on the form and then i am swapping the positions of the desired controls.

For example I've created the following Items:

[Form1 Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWMHm.png)

1. `TableLayoutPanel1` (two columns, three rows)
2. `TextBox1` Read-only = True, BackColor = White
3. `ComboBox1` Visible = False, DropDownStyle = DropDownList, FlatStyle = Popup
4. `Button1` (named it to Change)
5. `Button2` (named it to Done) -> Visible = False

[Runtime - Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E0zN.png)

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub SwapControls(tlp As TableLayoutPanel, ctr1 As Control, ctr2 As Control)
        Dim ctl1pos As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition = tlp.GetPositionFromControl(ctr1)
        ctr1.Visible = False
        tlp.SetCellPosition(ctr1, tlp.GetPositionFromControl(ctr2))
        ctr2.Visible = True
        tlp.SetCellPosition(ctr2, ctl1pos)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel1, TextBox1, ComboBox1)
        SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel1, Button1, Button2)
        Label1.Select()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel1, ComboBox1, TextBox1)
        SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel1, Button2, Button1)
        Label1.Select()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Select()
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

        TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    End Sub
End Class
```